# This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty

Tags: php, xml

Im unable to find out the solution , please help. below is the code. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $Lname = $_POST['lastName'];
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    echo $name.$Lname.$num;


    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Person></Person>");
    Header('Content-type:text/xml');
    $name = $xml->addChild('name',$name);
    $Lname = $xml->addChild('LastName',$Lname);
    $Number = $xml->addChild('Number',$num);


    print($xml->asXML());

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>XML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype= multipart/form-data>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="Name" required/>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" value="LName" required/>
        <input type="text" name="number" value="Number" required/>
        <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Im unable to find out the solution , please help. below is the code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `<form>` in the `else` part and remove the unneccesary `echo` statement.

### The working code..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    header('Content-type:text/xml');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $Lname = $_POST['lastName'];
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    //echo $name.$Lname.$num; //<---- Commented


    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Person></Person>");

    $name = $xml->addChild('name',$name);
    $Lname = $xml->addChild('LastName',$Lname);
    $Number = $xml->addChild('Number',$num);


    print($xml->asXML());

}
else
{
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>XML</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype= multipart/form-data>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Name" required/>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" value="LName" required/>
    <input type="text" name="number" value="Number" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
<Person>
<name>Nameasdasd</name>
<LastName>LNameasdasd</LastName>
<Number>Number32424</Number>
</Person>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not mix XML and HTML in that way. It invalidates the XML document.

1. Remove:

   ```
   echo $name.$Lname.$num;
   ```

   [Ref. prolog.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-prolog-dtd) This is what causes the error you witness.
2. Abort script on form data (or use an *else* clause):

   ```
   print($xml->asXML());
   exit(0);
   ```

   Else you get data in *trailing section* of XML-document.

For valid HTML you also need to add a [value for *action*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/form-submission.html#attr-fs-action) in the form. Quotes on attribute values are [usually optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-unquoted), but would advice consistency, thus also quote *enctype*.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype= multipart/form-data>
```

replace it with

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Miss `"` in enctype add it first